# How do I control that only numbers are entered from a text type edittext on Android Studio Java?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I created an edittext for IP control. After entering a certain amount of numbers, I automatically add a dot to the text. I do this with the addTextChangedListener. Since I made the input type text on the XML side, it also allows letter input, but this should not happen. For the solution, I made the xml input type number and this time the addTextChangedListener part is broken because it receives editable value as input. How can I fix it?

I am trying taking only digit from text type input but letter also printing because of text type.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the combination of InputType.Number with Textwatcher to achieve what you want. Here is the basic overview of what you are trying to achieve.

```
ipAddressEditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
            if (!editable.isNullOrBlank()) {
                val currentText = editable.toString()
                val dottedText= currentText.filter { it.isDigit() }

val formattedText = buildString {
                    var currentIndex = 0
                    for (i in 1..4) {
                        val endIndex = (currentIndex + 3).coerceAtMost(dottedtext.length)
                        append(dottedText.substring(currentIndex, endIndex))
                        if (endIndex < dottedText.length) {
                            append('.')
                        }
                        currentIndex = endIndex
                    }
                }

              

                if (currentText != formattedText) {
                    ipAddressEditText.setText(formattedText)
                    ipAddressEditText.setSelection(formattedText.length)
                }
            }
        }
    })
```